# core data freezes the app on multiple save

Tags: core-data, moc

I have problem in saving the data in core data. I have to save multiple book information in  the data base on click of button. When I click on the button I call the method and save the book information in data base. For the first three clicks it is fine saves the book info and ui is also responsive.  When I click on the button the fourth time then ui gets freeze at the end of the saving.

The code is given below.

```
+(void) storeBookInfo:(NSDictionary *) bookInfo inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) ctx {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *tempCtx = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [tempCtx setPersistentStoreCoordinator:appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [tempCtx setUndoManager:nil];

    NSNotificationCenter *notify = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notify addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                 object:tempCtx];

    NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:tempCtx];
    [req setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bid==%@", [bookInfo objectForKey:@"bid"]];
    [req setPredicate:predicate];

    [req setFetchLimit:1];
    [req setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSArray *bookObjects = [tempCtx executeFetchRequest:req error:nil];
    if([bookObjects count] > 0){
        NSError *err;
        Book *wi = [bookObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        wi.purchaseInfo = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[bookInfo objectForKey:@"purchaseInfo"] intValue]];
        if (![tempCtx save:&err]) {
            NSLog(@"Problem saving book info..");
            NSLog(@"err: %@", [err userInfo]);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
            [tempCtx undo];
            tempCtx = nil;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Book saved. in if part");
            tempCtx = nil;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        }
    }
    else {

        Book *book = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:tempCtx];
        book.bid     = [bookInfo objectForKey:@"bid"];
        book.title  = [bookInfo objectForKey:@"title"];
        book.thumbnailImgId = [bookInfo objectForKey:@"imageUrl"];
        book.downloadState  = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        book.pid = [bookInfo objectForKey:@"pid"];
        book.purchaseInfo = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[bookInfo objectForKey:@"purchaseInfo"] intValue]];
        book.discription = [bookInfo objectForKey:@"desc"];
        NSError *err;
        if (![tempCtx save:&err]) {
            NSLog(@"Problem saving book ifo..");
            NSLog(@"err: %@", [err userInfo]);
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
            [tempCtx undo];
            tempCtx = nil;

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Book saved.");
            tempCtx = nil;
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        }
    }

}

+ (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    AppDelegate *theDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[theDelegate managedObjectContext]          performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];

}
```

I have create a temporary MOC since the code is in background thread and after each save I send the notification.

For the fourth click on the button app get freeze. I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

*Assumptions:

`+storeBookInfo:inContext:` is always called in BG thread

Using ARC

*Please note:

`self` in `+storeBookInfo:inContext:` is the class itself, `removeObserver:` on it will remove all observation information (you might miss a merge for certain timings, consider using `removeObserver:name:object:` instead, and not nullifying tempCtx right away)

You are using: `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` but not using it's `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` methods (consider using `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`)

If `+mergeChanges:` will ever get called on the main thread your application will get stuck
(consider adding:

```
    NSAssert(![NSThread isMainThread],@"The application will get stuck");
```

to make sure, or revise your merge flow
)